# Userscript to change Links

Tags: javascript, replace, userscripts

Im just trying to make a quick userscript to chnage a .com link into a .co.uk link, I looked at this question ( [jQuery replacing relative links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520730/jquery-replacing-relative-links) ) to try get some ideas and came up with this, but its not working.

theres a link to the script as well as the script below, but i cant see what im doing wrong. I did try it beofre hand with

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

but didnt know if that was supported in userscripts, so ditched i, still no luck.

http://www.seriousbrew.co.uk/scripts/FreeBooksLinkReplace.user.js

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Free Books Link Replace
// @namespace   www.seriousbrew.co.uk/scripts/
// @description one hundred freee books, changing links to .co.uk from .com
// @include     http://onehundredfreebooks.com/ 
// @version     2
// ==/UserScript==


function replacelinks() {
      $("a[href^='/']").each(function(){ 
      var cur_href = $(this).attr("href");
      var n=str.replace(/.com/gi, ".co.uk"); 
    });
}

replacelinks();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", replaceLinks, false );

if( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
    replaceLinks();
}

function replaceLinks() {
    Array.forEach( document.links, function(a) {
        a.href = a.href.replace( ".com", ".co.uk" );
    });
}
```

Comment: no luck, i thought maybe the page just wasnt reaching a ready state and made a quick blank page but still no luck either http://www.seriousbrew.co.uk/scripts/test.php

Comment: @RudigerKidd wait a second, do you want to change all .com links to co.uk? The edited script will do that